# Spring data native query does not allow Postgres jsonb string exist operator (question mark)

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-data

I am trying to user Postgres jsonb string exist operator in the SpringData native query.

SpringData method example:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT t.id \n"
        + " FROM task AS t \n"
        + " WHERE (t.worker_ids \\? :workerId)\n"
        + " ORDER BY t.created_at\n",
        nativeQuery = true)
Optional<String> findMatchingTaskId(@Param("workerId") String workerId);
```

Where `worker_ids`is of type JSOB in the database. 
I've tried to exclude question mark with `\\` but still got below error : 
`org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: No value specified for parameter 2.`

Is there a way to use this operator with spring data native query?

Comment: A kind of workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50488457/5380322

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All operators in PostgreSQL uses underlying procedure:

```
> SELECT oprname, oprcode FROM pg_operator WHERE oprname LIKE '%?%'

oprname | oprcode
--------------------------
?       | jsonb_exists
?|      | jsonb_exists_any
?&      | jsonb_exists_all
...
```

So you can rewrite your query using `jsonb_exists(jsonb, text)` like this:

```
SELECT t.id
FROM task AS t
WHERE jsonb_exists(t.worker_ids, :workerId)
ORDER BY t.created_at
```