# How to escape question mark (?) character with Spring JpaRepository

Tags: postgresql, spring-data-jpa, jsonb

Postgres defines [additional jsonb Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-json.html) such as `?|`.

However, using Spring JpaRepository query builder, interrogation character is always considered as a parameter, and I can't figure how to escape it (except inside a single quote string, but then the query is invalid).

Example:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM public.user u WHERE u.authorities ?| array['ROLE_1', 'ROLE_2']", nativeQuery = true)
```

Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to resolve given parameter name [1] to QueryParameter reference
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryParameterBindingsImpl.resolveQueryParameter(QueryParameterBindingsImpl.java:520)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryParameterBindingsImpl.getQueryParameterListBinding(QueryParameterBindingsImpl.java:498)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.setParameterList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:560)
```

Is there a way to escape it, or a different solution to be able to use theses postgres native operators containing `?` character.

Trying to escape it with ??| or \?| does not work currently.

Note: I also tried to use a custom dialect function, but it ends with the same issue.

Libraries:

- hibernate 5.2.16
- hibernate-jpa 2.1
- spring-data-jpa 2.0.6.RELEASE
- postgresql 42.2.2

Thanks for your responses guys!

Comment: (Solution 1) Try adding one more `?`. I think this should work. So put `??|` as an operator. It does work with JDBC, so I'm unsure if it does with JPA. (Solution 2) Execute is at raw SQL, not prepared statement (Solution 3) Create a wrapper function for this operator in PL/pgSQL. Beware though, it will require functional index to work fast on large amount of data.

Comment: There is no need to create wrappers for operators. Postgres lets users create their own operators, so you can check definition for `?|` and name it for example `^|`. I have tested this and works just fine.

Comment: Any recent JDBC driver allows you to use two quotation marks instead, e.g. `??|` instead of `?|`

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński Could you please share your experience?

Comment: @Cepr0 You mean post as answer? I think that escaping question marks is easier to maintain and use. But overall, [create syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createoperator.html) and operator definition can be found here: `select * from pg_operator where oprname = '?|' and oprleft = (select oid from pg_type where typname = 'jsonb');`. It is easier to just use pgAdmin or other tool that will display create statement when browsing existing operators (in pg_catalog).

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński I created the custom operator instead of '?' but queries with it don't use indexes (on json fields). So it seems as useless ((

Comment: @Cepr0 Right, I forgot about index. You can make it work by adding operator class, then add that to operator family. Or by dropping existing one and recreating it with additional operator. But that I did not try, just TL;DR; from documentation. Seems like too much work for something that already has better solution.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I tried to escape '?' with '??' but got the exception: `org.hibernate.QueryException: Expected positional parameter count: 2, actually detected 0`. (I use Spring Data Jpa / Hibernate and PostgreSQL driver 42.2.1). Did you try it in Spring?..

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński Could you please give an example how to deal with 'op class/family'?

Comment: @Cepr0 Since it seems like escaping `?` does not work I will post my answer with custom operator and operator class for indexing. I have already tested index and it works as well with custom class. I will need to wait for longer break during work or I'll do it when I get back home tho.

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński thanks in advance!

Comment: Just added a workaround using a custom operator.

Comment: This related post describes each operator's underlying procedure mapping, which you can use instead. I.e. `jsonb_exists_any(u.attributes, array['ROLE_1', 'ROLE_2'])`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50041594/spring-data-native-query-does-not-allow-postgres-jsonb-string-exist-operator-qu?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In case escaping `?` is not possible, you can create duplicate operator with different name.

### New operator

Syntax for [creating operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createoperator.html) in Postgres:

```
CREATE OPERATOR name (
    PROCEDURE = function_name
    [, LEFTARG = left_type ] [, RIGHTARG = right_type ]
    [, COMMUTATOR = com_op ] [, NEGATOR = neg_op ]
    [, RESTRICT = res_proc ] [, JOIN = join_proc ]
    [, HASHES ] [, MERGES ]
)
```

In case of `?|` used in `jsonb` it will be:

```
CREATE OPERATOR ^|(
  PROCEDURE = jsonb_exists_any,
  LEFTARG = jsonb,
  RIGHTARG = _text,
  RESTRICT = contsel,
  JOIN = contjoinsel);
```

I have used `^|` as an example, alternative name. It can be any sequence from this list: `+ - * / < > = ~ ! @ # % ^ & |` ?`.

You can find current definition for operator you are interested in by querying [pg_catalog.pg_operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-operator.html) table.

```
SELECT oid, *
  FROM pg_catalog.pg_operator
 WHERE oprname = '?|'
   AND oprleft = (SELECT oid FROM pg_type WHERE typname = 'jsonb');
```

You can also use GUI tool like pgAdmin and browse `pg_catalog` to get SQL definition ready for reuse.

### Enabling index

If you want to use index for this "new" operator, you will require to create new operator class and optionally family. In our case, we need both, since we can't add it to existing family, because default operator is already taking [strategy slot](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xindex.html#XINDEX-STRATEGIES).

Just like with operators, it is recommended to use GUI tool like pgAdmin to browse operator classes and just copy&paste it.

First, we take OID of operator we made duplicate of:

```
SELECT oid, *
  FROM pg_catalog.pg_operator
 WHERE oprname = '?|'
   AND oprleft = (SELECT oid FROM pg_type WHERE typname = 'jsonb');
```

Same thing for operator family (we will get it from [operator class table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-opclass.html) instead), we are looking for gin class as this is the one that supports `?|`. `opcdefault` is used, because there is optional class `jsonb_path_ops` that does not support this operator:

```
SELECT opcfamily
  FROM pg_opclass
 WHERE opcintype = (SELECT oid FROM pg_type WHERE typname = 'jsonb')
   AND opcmethod = (SELECT oid FROM pg_am WHERE amname = 'gin')
   AND opcdefault
```

Then we get [strategy used by operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-amop.html) we duplicated:

```
SELECT amopstrategy,
       (SELECT typname FROM pg_type WHERE oid = amoplefttype) AS left_t, 
       (SELECT typname FROM pg_type WHERE oid = amoprighttype) AS right_t,*
FROM pg_amop
WHERE amopfamily = 4036 --family oid
  AND amopopr = 3248 --operator oid
```

Then [functions used by class](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-amproc.html):

```
SELECT amprocnum, amproc::text, pg_get_function_identity_arguments(amproc::oid) AS args,
      (SELECT typname FROM pg_type WHERE oid = amproclefttype) AS left_t,
      (SELECT typname FROM pg_type WHERE oid = amprocrighttype) AS right_t,*
FROM pg_amproc
WHERE amprocfamily = 4036 --op family
```

This brings us to this [operator class](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createopclass.html). It will create operator family if it does not exists already.

```
CREATE OPERATOR CLASS jsonb_ops_custom
   FOR TYPE jsonb USING gin AS
   OPERATOR 10  ^|(jsonb, _text),
   FUNCTION 1  gin_compare_jsonb(text, text),
   FUNCTION 2  gin_extract_jsonb(jsonb, internal, internal),
   FUNCTION 3  gin_extract_jsonb_query(jsonb, internal, smallint, internal, internal, internal, internal),
   FUNCTION 4  gin_consistent_jsonb(internal, smallint, jsonb, integer, internal, internal, internal, internal),
   FUNCTION 6  gin_triconsistent_jsonb(internal, smallint, jsonb, integer, internal, internal, internal);
```

Now you just need to create index using operator name that was created, something like:

```
CREATE INDEX ON jsonb_table USING gin(jsonb_column jsonb_ops_custom)
```

And you should be able to use index:

```
SET enable_seqscan = off;
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT * FROM jsonb_table WHERE jsonb_column ^| array['b', 'c'];
```

Comment: In my Postgres (13.2) I see that for `?|`  `oprrest = matchingsel` and `oprjoin = matchingjoinsel` while for `^|` you have `oprrest = contsel` and `oprjoin = contjoinsel`. Is this a deliberate departure, or are the `?|` operator's fields different in the version of Postgres you ran?

Answer (score 10):

You can use direct call to a function `jsonb_exists_any()`.
So in your case it would be

`jsonb_exists_any(u.authorities::jsonb, array['ROLE_1', 'ROLE_2'])`

Comment: Be aware that most jsonb function do not make use of an index even if the corresponding operator does!

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround for that specific case, I created a custom operator:

```
CREATE OPERATOR ~~~| (
    LEFTARG = jsonb,
    RIGHTARG = _text,
    PROCEDURE = pg_catalog.jsonb_exists_any
)
```

Then in my query: `WHERE u.authorities ~~~| array['ROLE_1', 'ROLE_2']`

@ŁukaszKamiński detailed this workaround in his answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50488457/1097926