# How to run native postgres query using spring-data-jpa

Tags: postgresql, spring-data-jpa

I am using `spring-data-jpa` to run native `postgres` queries. The query is performed on entity's jsonb data. 
I can run the raw query on db server with success:

```
SELECT e.* 
FROM public.entity e where e.json ? 'salary' and e.json ->> 'salary' > '10000';
```

But, since `spring-data-jpa` also supports `?` for the parameterized queries, there seems to be conflict in the grammer of the query, therefore application eventually fails to even start.

```
@Query(value = "select e.* from Entity e where e.json ? 'salary' and e.json->> 'salary' > ?1", nativeQuery = true)
List<Lead> getEntitiesBySalaryGreaterThan(String value);
```

}

Please let me know the workaround or correct way of executing the intended native query in `spring-data-jpa` env

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible that you need to escape `?` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50464741/how-to-escape-question-mark-character-with-spring-jparepository)?

Comment: I already have that, If you see ur @query it has two nativeQuery

Comment: Thanks man!! Did not know that postgres allows creating custom operators