# Native query on Spring Boot: Mixing of ? parameters and other forms like ?1 is not supported

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm running a native query on spring boot jpa with Postgresql/PostGIS.

The query is running fine on postgresql:

```
WITH data AS (SELECT '{ "type": "Point", "coordinates": [102.0, 0.5]

     }'::jsonb AS fc) 
UPDATE dopigp.disciplinare_aree SET area_da_validare=( 
SELECT 
  ST_Union(ST_AsText(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(feat->>'geometry'))) AS geom 
FROM ( 
  SELECT  
    CASE  
        WHEN fc ? 'features' THEN jsonb_array_elements(fc->'features') 
        WHEN fc ? 'geometry' THEN (fc) 
        ELSE jsonb_build_object('geometry', fc) 
    END  
    AS feat 
  FROM data 
) AS f 
) WHERE id_disciplinare=251
```

On Spring Boot give me the error: ***Mixing of ? parameters and other forms like ?1 is not supported***

```
@Transactional
@Modifying
@Query(value = "WITH data AS (SELECT (?2)\\:\\:jsonb AS fc)\n" + 
        "UPDATE dopigp.disciplinare_aree SET area_da_validare=(\n" + 
        "SELECT\n" + 
        "  ST_Union(ST_AsText(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(feat->>'geometry'))) AS geom\n" + 
        "FROM (\n" + 
        "  SELECT \n" + 
        "   CASE \n" + 
        "       WHEN fc ? 'features' THEN jsonb_array_elements(fc->'features')\n" + 
        "       WHEN fc ? 'geometry' THEN (fc)\n" + 
        "       ELSE jsonb_build_object('geometry', fc)\n" + 
        "   END \n" + 
        "   AS feat\n" + 
        "  FROM data\n" + 
        ") AS f\n" + 
        ") WHERE id_disciplinare=(?1) \n",
        nativeQuery = true)
void upload(Integer idDisciplinare, String geoJSON);
```

Comment: So the actual question is how to make it so the question marks in the query are not seen by hibernate as parameter placeholders.

Comment: `?` is the placeholder for prepared statement parameters.

Comment: The placeholder ?1 is for input, instead the the placeholder in  *fc ? 'features'* mean *fc contains features?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it's not possible to escape the question mark. 
So the only solution was to create a custom operator to substitute the question mark as pointed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50488457/1878854) and use it in the native query instead of "***?***".

Comment: `@Param("jsonOperator") jsonOperator: String = "?"`

Comment: @JackMahoney Could you elaborate further as to where this annotation must go?

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the ? in the case statement because this is the parameter placeholder but instead of \ you have to use ? :

```
 WHEN fc ??
```

Comment: Hmm but what is ? standing for? Shouldn't it be a =

Comment: fc ? 'features' means: fc contain features

Comment: Oh I was wrong sorry. You have to use ? not \ as the escape sequence

Comment: Maybe I can't escape it (if the problem is this) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50464741/how-to-escape-question-mark-character-with-spring-jparepository

Comment: have you tried with two ?? because this is the offical JDBC escape

Comment: In that case Hibernate does not comply to the JDBC standard and you have to go for the other solution