# Character ? causes error on EntityManager::createNativeQuery

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, postgis, hibernate-entitymanager

I have this query above:

```
SELECT p.id, p.constraint_id, p.distance, p.height, p.coordinates, p.gtype, p.name FROM geometry p WHERE p.gtype='PolylineVolume' AND path(polygon(box(point(15.740013406952562 - (180/pi()) * (p.distance/(6378137*cos(pi()*15.740013406952562/180))),46.97849625047054 - (180/pi()) * (p.distance/6378137)),point(16.007686681509206 + (180/pi()) * (p.distance/(6378137*cos(pi()*16.007686681509206/180))),47.07276572929793 + (180/pi()) * (p.distance/6378137))))) ?# popen(p.coordinates)
```

and when I am trying to execute it with the help of `EntityManager::createQuery`
I am getting the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException:
>   Expected positional parameter count: 1, actual parameters: [] [SELECT
>   p.id, p.constraint_id, p.distance, p.height, p.coordinates, p.gtype,
>   p.name FROM geometry p WHERE p.gtype='PolylineVolume' AND
>   path(polygon(box(point(15.180269398356009 - (180/pi()) *
>   (p.distance/(6378137*cos(pi()*15.180269398356009/180))),47.15207765669525
>   - (180/pi()) * (p.distance/6378137)),point(16.169955064019394 + (180/pi()) *
>   (p.distance/(6378137*cos(pi()*16.169955064019394/180))),47.49782020196999
>   + (180/pi()) * (p.distance/6378137))))) ?# popen(p.coordinates)]

It appears that the intersect operator `?#` is causing the problem

Comment: I fear you have to define a custom operator (in postgres ..without `?` character), since jpa "cannot escape '?'" (and `?`is a parameter placeholder...which explains the error message) ...https://stackoverflow.com/q/50464741/592355

Comment: @xerx593 can I use the `?#` to define the new operator?

Comment: Yes, inside the new operator, you could use `?#`. And even better approach, if you could write  `INTERSECT` into the (native-jpa) query ...avoiding the `?`

Comment: @xerx593 i think not `?#` operator is not a intersect operator between sets it is an operator for geometry types...

Comment: ..then (if no one knows "built-in"), please try the custom operand workaround