# How to pass parameter in array type in postgres query in JPA native query

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-data-jpa

I need to write a query in JPA where it can fetch all the passed values in the parameter(list) in the DB and return the data.

With the help of this post - [How to escape question mark (?) character with Spring JpaRepository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50464741/how-to-escape-question-mark-character-with-spring-jparepository/58932986#58932986?newreg=f6788144bc1c47678d5ed6f417c0fd68)
I was able to convert the list to array and make the query something like this
**select * from dashboards d WHERE jsonb_exists_any(d.roles_access, array['Role1']);**
it works fine in pgAdmin, however in jpa it cant cast the parameter userRoles

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM dashboards d WHERE jsonb_exists_any(d.roles_access, array[:userRoles])", nativeQuery = true)
  List<Dashboard> findAllDashboardsByUserRole(@Param("userRoles")  final String [] userRoles);
```

I have tried many ways like **array[CAST(:userRoles to jsonb)]** but nothing works.
Any suggestion on how to properly cast it would be appreciated