Mixing of ? parameters and other forms like ?1 is not supported Postgres
I am trying to create a native query using spring JPA for the below query. I am trying to filter the data where the jsonB contains the filtered key.
select * FROM targeted_event_catalog e WHERE e.severity_map ? 'serviceName';

So far I have done this
  @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM targeted_event_catalog e WHERE e.severity_map ? :service", nativeQuery = true)
  List<TargetedEventRegistration> findByService(@Param("service") String service);

But I get the below error
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mixing of ? parameters and other forms like ?1 is not supported

The severity_map in a postgres column is a jsonb type. This is how data looks,
{"serviceName": ["info", "warning", "critical"]}

I wanted to know anything missing here? I have also tried adding two ?? but it did not work and threw the same error.

Seems related to this issue (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/issues/2551), have you also tried escaping the question mark with \ or \?

Also, try to see this other issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50464741/how-to-escape-question-mark-character-with-spring-jparepository

I tried with \?..but i got the same error. I basically want to filter the data if any of map data contains a passed the key. Do we have any other postgres function i could use?

You can switch to a containment check with e.severity_map @> '{"serviceName":{}}' (if it was an object) or a JSONPath predicate e.severity_map @@ 'exists($.serviceName)'. Both operators are supported by the GIN index. If you don't care about the index, the function behind ? operator is jsonb_exists(e.severity_map,'serviceName').

Thanks to @Zegarek comment. I was able to fix this. I used jsonb_exists(e.severity_map,?1) (passing service name as a param) and this fixed the issue.
final query
"SELECT * FROM targeted_event_catalog e WHERE jsonb_exists(e.severity_map,?1)"

